# If statement with two conditions not working properly

Tags: java, parsing

I am new to programming and I am trying to create a program which parses a file and outputs the tokens. At the minute I am trying to create an if statement which will output the name of each operator with two characters, e.g. "&&" or "<=". My if statement does not work for "<=" as it picks up the '<" and '=' separately due to the earlier code:

```
else if (getOp(ch) != null) {
                System.out.println(line + ", " + sglchar + ", "+ ch);
                counter++;
                continue;
            }
```

My getOp(ch) method contains the operators with one character,  however I cannot figure out how to do this with two character operators and my if statements don't seem to be doing the trick.

This is the if statement I am trying:

```
else if (prog.charAt(counter) == '<' && prog.charAt(counter+1) == '=') {
                    String str = "";
                    str += ch;
                    str += prog.charAt(counter++);
                    System.out.println(line + ", " + getOp(str) + ", " + str);
                    counter++;
                    continue;
                }
```

Comment: You've actually already identified what your problem is: "*My if statement does not work for "<=" as it picks up the '<" and '=' separately due to the earlier code*" - one solution to this is to move all of the code that checks for compound operators above the code that checks for single-character operators. Alternatively, you can nest the check for the second character inside the first `if` block.

Comment: @JavaMan Could you give an example of the file that you are trying to parse?

Comment: public class HelloWorld { 
 public static void main ( String [ ] args ) { 
 boolean b=false; 
 int a=10; 
 double b=0.5;
 double c=a+b*10 ; 
 System.out.println("The num is: " + c); 
} 
} 
<= It is a text file just to ensure my code works

Comment: @JavaMan Have you considered using Java's Scanner class? It makes parsing text files really easy. No loops or counters are necessary. Link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As outlined in my comments, use of Java's [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class. It makes parsing text files very easy.

Consider the following:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
while (sc.hasNext()) {
     String token = sc.next(); 
         if (Pattern.matches("<=", token)) {
             System.out.println(token);
         }
}
sc.close();
```

}

outputs:

```
   <=
```